# How to write this PHP array using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've the following `PHP` array (key value pair multi dimensional array)

```
$myarr = array (
'one' => array ('1one','2one','3one'),
'two',
'three',
'four' => array ('1four','2four'),
'five'
);
```

How to writ exact array using `JAVASCRIPT` ?

I'm not good in `javascript` but this is my failure try, i do not know if `javascript` support such type of arrays or not!

```
var myarr = [
{ 'one' : ['1one','2one','3one']},
{'two'},
{'three'},
{'four' : ['1four','2four']},
{'five'}
];
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($myarr);`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5705115a9f0759b679eb8746d6909b1d8fde81a

Comment: When you have anything in {} , then it has to be a key value pair, ,but inside [] you only have idexes, but every index you can nest more things.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myarr = [
{ 'one' : ['1one','2one','3one']},
'two',
'three',
{'four' : ['1four','2four']},
'five'
];
```

Comment: The JSON conversion PHP makes, differs: `{"one":["1one","2one","3one"],"0":"two","1":"three","four":["1four","2four"],"2":"five"}`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to keep things consistent in a key-value pair:

```
var myarr = [
  {'one' : ['1one','2one','3one']},
  {'two' : []},
  {'three' : []},
  {'four' : ['1four','2four']},
  {'five' : []}
];
```

Comment: `two` is value, not key